# Alternatives for std::enable_if and explicit overloading for template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, overload-resolution

Consider the following setup:

```
template< typename Held >
class Node{
  //...
};

template< typename Held >
class vNode{
  //...
};

template <typename... Graphs>
class Branch{
  //...
};

template <typename...> class Graph; // undefined

template< 
  typename    node_t
> class Graph< node_t >{  //specialization for an ending node
  //...
};

template< 
  typename    node_t,
  typename... Graphs
> class Graph< node_t, Branch< Graphs...> >{  //specialization for a mid-graph node
  //...
};

template<
  template <typename> class node_t,
  typename Held
> void f( Graph< Node<Held> > ) {
  //stuff A on a node
}

template<
  template <typename> class node_t,
  typename Held
> void f( Graph< const Node<Held> > ) {
  //stuff A on a const node
}

template<
  template <typename> class node_t,
  typename Held
> void f( Graph< vNode<Held> > ) {
  //stuff B on a virtual node
}

template<
  template <typename> class node_t,
  typename Held
> void f( Graph< const vNode<Held> > ) {
   //stuff B on a virtual const node
}

template<
  template <typename> class node_t,
  typename Held,
  typename... Graphs
> void f( Graph< Node<Held>, Branch<Graphs...>> ) {
  //stuff C on a node with a branch
}

template<
  template <typename> class node_t,
  typename Held,
  typename... Graphs
> void f( Graph< const Node<Held>, Branch<Graphs...> > ) {
  //stuff C on a const node with a branch
}

template<
  template <typename> class node_t,
  typename Held,
  typename... Graphs
> void f( Graph< vNode<Held>, Branch<Graphs...> > ) {
  //stuff D on a virtual node with a branch
}

template<
  template <typename> class node_t,
  typename Held,
  typename... Graphs
> void f( Graph< const vNode<Held>, Branch<Graphs...> > ) {
   //stuff D on a virtual const node with a branch
}
```

In other words - I'm creating a type that represents a graph. Nodes can be normal, or virtual, const and non-const. A Graph can contain a single node, or a node and a branch of graphs.

When I create a function `f` I want it to be const-neutral (do the same stuff on a const and non-const version of a node in a graph, but different on branched and unbranched graphs). Do I have to:

1. Duplicate the code?
2. Use `std::enable_if` hack?

   1. Duplication of code duplicates bugs, so it is not optimal.
   2. std::enable_if produces bad error messages in my case.

Is there a smarter solution to the problem that will make `f` accept const and non-const nodes?

Comment: Why not simply `template<class T> void f( Graph<T> )` and let `T` be deduced appropriately? You can always extract the node type easily with a trait class.

Comment: Why are `Graph< node_t >` and `Graph< node_t, Branch< Graphs... > >` the same `template` if they have different implementations, interfaces, and are used differently?  Or are there functions that treat them the same?  You can write a factory template that returns a different type based on if it is a terminal or not, for example.

Comment: @Yakk : There are 2 reasons: 1. A `Graph` is derived from `Branch<>`, which is a `std::tuple` wrapper. Since `std::tuple<>` is not zero size, I think that empty base optimization would not apply. 2. There are recursive functions that traverse the `Graph` and terminationg them on a terminal node requires a function overload. Overloading for `Graph<node_t, Branch<>>` is not much different form `Graph<node_t>` and the latter produces shorter errors and is more explicit in intent. @TC : That is an excellent idea which I went for. Thank you as always, this should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a template template parameter and have a gazillion overloads, just use a type template parameter:

```
template<class T> void f( Graph<T> ) { /*...*/ }
```

`T` will be deduced to be `Node<Foo>`, `vNode<Foo>` or `const Node<Foo>` etc. as appropriate. If `Node` vs `vNode` matters, you can always extract the type of the node with a simple trait class. Similarly, you can use `static_assert` together with a trait class to ensure that `T` is a specialization of `Node` or `vNode`.